# Homemade Teriyaki Sauce

Tags: food-safety

I would like to process (in glass jars or bottles for shelf life) teriyaki sauce/marinade. 
My recipe calls for vinegar. I'm leaning towards pressure cooking for safety reasons but am 
Unable to find somewhere to purchase bottles with tops that seal. Can you recommend somewhere or should I stick with my canning jars? These will not be for resale only home use or gifts. Thanks

Comment: A home brew supply store/website should be able to provide you with sealable bottles

Answer (score 1):

I use canning jars for my teriyaki which I seal in a boiling bath for 15 minutes. You can find canning jars and lids at many grocery stores as well as some hardware stores and variety stores such as Walmart.